# Gstreamer playing audio and video together

Tags: h.264, gstreamer, aac

I was trying to learn about gstreamer pipelines. Now I want to play an mp4 video containing h264 encoded videos frames and aac encoded audio samples.
for playing video samples I used the following pipeline

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=~/samples/step_up_dance_1080p.mp4 ! qtdemux name=dmux dmux.video_00 ! h264parse ! ffdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```

I  used the following pipeline for playing audio alone

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=~/samples/step_up_dance_1080p.mp4 ! qtdemux name=dmux dmux.audio_00 ! aacparse ! faad ! autoaudiosink
```

Both are working fine, But I want to combine both audio and video. How do I do it ?
I tried

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=~/samples/step_up_dance_1080p.mp4 ! qtdemux name=dmux dmux.video_00 ! h264parse ! ffdec_h264 ! autovideosink  dmux.audio_00 ! aacparse ! faad ! autoaudiosink
```

But it was not working.
How do I play audio and video together ?

Answer (score 3):

First, when saying that somethng does not work, please tell what happens. Incase the pipeline stalls, you just forgot the queue elements which create new threads for the decoders.

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=~/samples/step_up_dance_1080p.mp4 ! qtdemux name=dmux dmux.video_00 ! queue ! h264parse ! ffdec_h264 ! autovideosink  dmux.audio_00 ! queue ! aacparse ! faad ! autoaudiosink
```

Just using playbin is simpler. Take a look at the pipeline layout.

```
GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR=$PWD gst-launch-0.10 playbin2 uri=file://$HOME/samples/step_up_dance_1080p.mp4
```

and render the dot files it created using graphviz (dot -Tsvg xxx.dot -o xxx.svg).

Comment: That will work for sure... I was trying to learn about pipelines..  I was searching how we can do these parallely.

Comment: How could I do this with separate files/URLs for audio and video?

Comment: Please post a new question. You can use two sources (one for each file) with their respective decoders and sinks. The video will by default be synced to the audio clock.