# Gst-launch How do i edit this pipeline so play the audio?

Tags: gstreamer, gst-launch-1.0

As title, how can I change this so it also plays the files audio too?

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location='/usr/share/myfile.mp4' ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! imxvpudec ! imxipuvideosink framebuffer=/dev/fb2 &
```

The I can get the file to play with audio using

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v playbin uri=file:///path/to/somefile.mp4
```

But I need the output to be onto device fb2 like in the first example

Many thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gstreamer playing audio and video together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319526/gstreamer-playing-audio-and-video-together)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted a link to this question into the gstreamer reddit and a hero called Omerzet saved the day.

The following is the solution:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location='/usr/share/myfile.mp4' ! qtdemux name=demux demux.video_0 ! queue ! h264parse ! imxvpudec ! imxipuvideosink framebuffer=/dev/fb2 demux.audio_0 ! queue ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! alsasink device="sysdefault:CARD=imxhdmisoc"
```

Where framebuffer diverts the video to device /dev/fb2.

And

alsasink device="sysdefault:CARD=imxhdmisoc"
Diverts the audio to my define sound card.